# How to use overload operator as condition in a if statment?

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, operator-overloading

Here is the class

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
  protected:
    int x, y;
    double operator-(const Point &def){ 
        return sqrt(pow((x-def.x),2.0)+ 
                  pow((y-def.y),2.0));
    }

};

class Circle: public Point {
  private:
    int radius;

  public:
  Circle(){     
    this->x=x;
    this->y=y;
    this->radius=radius;
  }

  Circle(int x, int y, int radius){
this->x=x;
this->y=y;
this->radius=radius;
}
    void printCircleInfo() {
      cout << x << " " << y << " " << radius << " " ;
    }
```

> This is the operator I want to be the condition in my if statement.

```
bool operator==(const Circle &def){ 
  return (x==def.x) & (y==def.y) & (radius==def.radius);
}
    bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(Circle anotherCircle){
      if (anotherCircle.radius + radius >=   *this - anotherCircle    )
    return true;
      return false;
    }

};
```

Here is main

```
int main(){
  int x,y,radius;
  const int SIZE = 13;
  Circle myCircleArry[SIZE];
  myCircleArry[0] = Circle(5,3,9);
   cout << endl;
   myCircleArry[0].printCircleInfo(); cout << " ; ";
  ifstream Lab6DataFileHandle;

  Lab6DataFileHandle.open("Lab6Data.txt");
  while (!Lab6DataFileHandle.eof( )) {
 for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
Lab6DataFileHandle>>x;
Lab6DataFileHandle>>y;
Lab6DataFileHandle>>radius;
 myCircleArry[i] = Circle(x,y,radius);

 if (myCircleArry[0].doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(myCircleArry[i])) {
      myCircleArry[i].printCircleInfo(); cout << " ; ";
```

> Here is the If statement

```
      if ( operator==( Circle &def))
 {cout <<"*";
}


  }
  }
}
  Lab6DataFileHandle.close();

}
```

> How do I use the overloaded operator as the condition of the if statement? If you need any clarification just ask other wise please leave an example in your answer.
> Thank you for your time.

Comment: `if (operator==(Circle &def))` is invalid.    It would need to be either `if (some_circle.operator== (some_other_circle))` or (implicitly calling the `operator==()` function) `if (some_circle == some_other_circle)`.     Also, since your `operator==()` is a member function, the function should be qualified `const` to reflect that fact that `a == b` generally changes neither `a` or `b`.

Comment: It doesn't help that your code declares functions when it should be using them.   Declaring a function and calling it are different actions, performed using different syntax, and you are declaring it in places where you expect to call it.   Read your introductory C++ text a bit better - guessing how to do things, as you obviously are, will not work.

Comment: Where in my program do I declare a function when I expect to call it?

Comment: Anywhere in the source file that contains the call BEFORE (i.e. above) the point where it is called.   For the member function of the class, that means the class definition must also be before the point where it is called  (since a member function cannot be called without visibility of the class definition).    The declarations can also be in a header file, as long as that header file is `#include`d before the code that attempts to use the declarations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A == needs two arguments (even if the overload is a member), you would write the if as any other if statement:

```
if(circle1 == circle2) { ... }
```

and if there's a matching overload the compiler would transform that into something like:

```
if(circle1.operator ==(circle2)) { ... }
```

Comment: Ok but is there a way so that when the overload operater returns true the if statement is true and when it returns false the if statement is false?

Comment: That's literally what the equality operator is supposed to do. Looks like you're using it wrong at a glance.